# WatchOS2 Deploy to target : Could not build module 'Healthkit'

Tags: ios9, healthkit, watchos-2

I am trying to build an app using health kit and I am not able to deploy on to apple watch. I literally don't have any code written, it just refuses to compile HealthKit framework when deploying onto the device..

Anyone has any ideas?

I am using GM SDK.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey @sdw. Welcome to SO. What exactly is happening when you try to deploy the application? Do you get some error? Please update your question adding more details about that. You may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured this out, it was a bundle identifier issue with watchkit app and watchkit extension. Naming conventions.